# how to vertically align two items to two different levels in a container

Tags: html, css

In the figma file that I have (which I have attached), the logo is vertically centered. But the links on the right are slightly above the logo.

[image]

However, my code shows that both are vertically aligned:

I have tried using margin, padding, and height settings. None of them has worked. I am not sure what else to try.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-left: 75px;
}

.heading {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: green;
}

.heading .light_text {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.house img {
  height: 30px;
}

.nav_list {
  padding-right: 100px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.nav_list ul {
  display: flex;
  /* breaks the list horizontally */
  list-style-type: none;
  /* removes the bullet points */
}

.nav_list li {
  margin: auto 15px;
}

.nav_list a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="heading">
        <div class="logo_name">
          <h2><span class="bold_text">RENT</span><span class="light_text">HOMES</span></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="nav_list">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Amanda! Has your problem been solved? Did you try out the answers from all of us?

Answer (score 0):

I see that your question has changed...

Your vertical alignments can be done in a lot of ways, but I would
recommend using `align-items: flex-start` for your case.
If the menu has to be higher than the logo, then add some top
padding to your first cell. For narrow screens, you will probably
have to display the menu below the logo and reduce the top margin
of your logo.

I propose several improvements:

- Simplify a bit the HTML and use `<header>` and `<nav>` tags
  to improve the semantic of your HTML. This will help search
  engines and blind persons.
- When switching to the `border-box` model, don't forget to do
  it on pseudo-elements also. Usually, I set it on `<html>` or
  `<body>` and then inherit it on other elements. This makes
  the rule less aggressive and easier to override.
- Aligning and spacing elements with flexbox seems better than
  playing around with margins and paddings. This can be done
  with `align-items` and with gaps between elements.
- What about narrow screens? This can be solved by allowing
  the header elements to wrap below each other with
  `flex-wrap: wrap;`. To avoid them being too close, like I
  mentioned above, use `gap` or `column-gap` and `row-gap` to
  add space between them. You could even push it a bit further
  by adding a media query for narrow screens in order to display
  the menu items in a column instead of a row. Having full row
  clickable items for touch screens makes them easier to use for
  people with big fingers ;-)

```css
/* Import the "Lato" font from Google Fonts. */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  /* Set the box sizing model here and inherit it below. */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

/* For the demo, make the container div resizable horizontally. */
.resizable {
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: 1px solid silver;
  /* Enable @container queries on this element and name it. */
  container-type: inline-size;
  container-name: resizable;
}

/* Display a blinking "resize me" message at the bottom right. */
.resizable::after {
  content: "resize me →";
  color: silver;
  font-size: .8em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.3em;
  right: 1em;
  animation: blink 3s linear infinite;
}
/* The blink animation keyframes. */
@keyframes blink {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 1.5em;
  padding: 2em;
  /* Smooth resize for the @container query at 300px. */
  transition: .2s ease padding;
}

.navbar h2 {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: black;
  /* Move down the title (answer of your question). */
  padding-top: .5em;
}

.bold_text {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.light_text {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.navbar nav ul {
  /* Removes the bullet points. */
  list-style-type: none;
  /* Breaks the list horizontally but with wrapping. */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1em;
}

.navbar nav a,
.navbar nav a:link,
.navbar nav a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  /* Avoid having "About Us" or "Contact Us" on two lines. */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Put some space between the text and the underline made
     with the linear gradient. */
  padding-bottom: .2em;
}

/* Add a line below the links on hover, active or target. */
.navbar nav a:hover,
.navbar nav a:active,
.navbar nav a:target {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    90deg, transparent, black, transparent
  );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 1px;
  background-position: center bottom;
}

/*
Media queries:

Here I used @container queries for the demo. but in your
case it would be @media (max-width: ...) { ... }.

The @container queries are quite well supported since
2023 and have the advantage of building responsive widgets
that can be placed anywhere in a web page.
But for your case, as it's part of the main header of the
web page, it is best to use the fully supported @media
queries. I wasn't able to use them here for the demo
because the snippet is rendered in a part of the page and
I didn't want to force users to open it in full screen
mode to get it working.
*/

/* Based on the width of <div class="resizable"> */
@container resizable (max-width: 440px) {
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .navbar nav ul {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .navbar nav a {
    /* We can make them grow for easier clicks. */
    display: block;
  }
  
  .navbar nav a:hover,
  .navbar nav a:active,
  .navbar nav a:target {
    background-image: linear-gradient(
      90deg, black, transparent
    );
    background-size: 4em 1px;
    background-position: left bottom;
  }
}

@container resizable (max-width: 300px) {
  .navbar {
    /* Reduce the horizontal padding to have more space. */
    padding: 2em 1.5em;
    /* Reduce the font size of the title according to the container width. */
    font-size: min(1em, 8cqi);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container resizable">
  <header class="navbar">
    <h2>
      <span class="bold_text">RENT</span><span class="light_text">HOMES</span>
    </h2>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about-us">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#reviews">Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Using semantics does not only *help blind persons* but any person who uses assistive technologies such as screen readers. Frankly, blind persons are only a small portion of users who use screen readers.

Comment: @tacoshy You are totally right. It was just a way to point out the problem if the HTML semantic is poor.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest thing is to use `transform: translateY`. However, this is not best practice

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div,li {box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #ddd;} /* remove */

html {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-left: 75px;
}

.heading {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: green;
}

.heading .light_text {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.house img {
  height: 30px;
}

.nav_list {
  padding-right: 100px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  transform: translateY(-2rem); /* magic is here */
}

.nav_list ul {
  display: flex;
  /* breaks the list horizontally */
  list-style-type: none;
  /* removes the bullet points */
}

.nav_list li {
  margin: auto 15px;
}

.nav_list a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="heading">
        <div class="logo_name">
          <h2><span class="bold_text">RENT</span><span class="light_text">HOMES</span></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="nav_list">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: not really responsive to hardcode an offset instead of using `50%`. Besides that, the OP already used flexbox why not use that to vertically align (`align-items: center`)?

Comment: It all depends on the layout. We only have a desktop option and no mobile. In addition, in the question the author asks how to make it so that it is not in the center, but higher.

Comment: Your snippet clearly shows that it is not in the center... hardcoding a fixed offset is rarely a working solution

Comment: @tacoshy Look carefully at the author's layout. Are the menu items in the center? Maybe your layout image is not loading?

Answer (score -1):

You can add some top margin to an element to move it lower down. In your case, just add a little top margin to `.logo_name`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
  gap: 1em;
}

.heading {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: green;
}

.heading .light_text {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.logo_name {
  margin: 0.5em 0;
}

.house img {
  height: 30px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="heading">
    <div class="logo_name">
      <h2><span class="bold_text">RENT</span><span class="light_text">HOMES</span></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About Us</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Reviews</a>
    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also try Removing All Padding and
Adding `Text-wrap: no wrap` to navlist and `aligin-items:flex-start`

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      html {
        font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
      }

      .navbar {
      padding: 25px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        border: 1px solid red;
      }

      .heading {
        display: flex;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        color: green;
      }

      .heading .light_text {
        font-weight: 500;
      }

      .house img {
        height: 30px;
      }

      .nav_list {
        font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: 500;
        display: flex;
        align-content: flex-start;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }

      .nav_list ul {
        display: flex;
        /* breaks the list horizontally */
        list-style-type: none;
        /* removes the bullet points */
      }

      .nav_list li {
        margin: auto 2px;
        font-size:10px
      }

      .nav_list a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: green;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="heading">
          <div class="logo_name">
            <h2>
              <span class="bold_text">RENT</span
              ><span class="light_text">HOMES</span>
            </h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav_list">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: You miss the question about vertically centering the navbar.